# WindowsError: [Error 126] when loading a OS with ctypes

Tags: python, c++, cygwin

The python code,it can not be work on Windows 7 platform.

```
def libSO():
  lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("./ConsoleApplication2.so")
  lib.cfoo2(1, 3)
```

When I tried running it, get the error message from python3.4.3......
I don't know why.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#8>", line 1, in <module>
    libSO()
  File "C:\Python34\test.py", line 12, in libSO
    lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("./ConsoleApplication2.so")
  File "C:\Python34\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 429, in LoadLibrary
    return self._dlltype(name)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 351, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found
```

The C++ code is:

```
#include<iostream>  
using namespace std;

void foo2(int a, int b)
{
    cout << a << " " << b << endl;
}

extern "C"
{
    void cfoo2(int a, int b)
    {
        foo2(a, b);
    }
}
```

I use Cygwin to compiled:
g++ ConsoleApplication2.cpp -shared -o ConsoleApplication2.so

I'm srue the library and the python file is in the same path(C:\Python34)

So why it can't be work?!

Comment: what is the working directory when you run the python script?

Comment: the directory is "C:\Python34\test.py"

Comment: the directory is "C:\Python34\test.py".I tried to use absolute path to replace the relative path.But it can't be work too.       lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("C://Python34//ConsoleApplication2.so")

Comment: It's crazy.  I use the command line is still invalid:  >>>import ctypes  >>>ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("C:\\Python34\\ConsoleApplication2.so")